# RTSP frame metadata extraction in Android

Tags: metadata, rtsp, libvlc

I have RTSP stream from my drone and it has embedded metadata which includes geo locations like longitude, latitude and altitude in each frame. Is there a way, I can extract these metadata in Android ? I am using VLC media player to render stream. Any help is appreciated as I am a new android developer.

Comment: can you find this metadata in the VLC UI when you play the stream in VLC app on any platform?

Comment: Yes, I can find the metadata on VLC but those are like artist, duration etc.  I am looking for metadata which was embedded by the server like latitude, longitude etc

Comment: for custom tags you will need to use another tool, libvlc is not a custom tag extractor

Comment: mfkl do you have any suggestions on tools to extract custom tags?

Comment: whatever your server is using to create custom tags would be a good start

Comment: maybe try taglib with ID3v2